# In C#, how do I call a method at random intervals on a separate thread but have it always process sequentially?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

This seems like it has a very simple solution, but I've been looking on and off for months without finding a definitive answer.

I have an object being created by the UI Thread. I'm actually creating several of the same type of object. Sometimes I'll create 1 or 2 every minute, sometimes I'll create 30 in a second. Each time an object it created, I need to perform some calculations on the object. The combination of potentially 30 objects created at in a short time, and the expensive calculations I'm performing on said objects can really lag the UI.

I've tried performing the calculations via Tasks and backgroundWorkers and all sorts of threading but they all perform the calculations out of order, and it's imperative that the objects are calculated in the order they are created and that one doesn't start it's calculations until the object ahead of it finishes it's own calculations.

I can find all sorts of information about how to perform these tasks in parallel, but can anyone explain to me how I can force them to happen sequentially, just not on the UI Thread? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to figure this out for months :(

Comment: Would it be sufficient if the calculations could run concurrently or out-of-order, and then be inserted back to a result list that restores the order (by reordering) ? A [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) with index as key and a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963556.aspx) (representing a future value) could be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the easiest way to run tasks in sequential order here is to use `Task.ContinueWith`. Note `TaskContinuationOptions.LazyCancellation`, it's used to make sure that cancellation doesn't break the order of the sequence:

```
Task _currentTask = Task.FromResult(Type.Missing);
readonly object _lock = new Object();

void QueueTask(Action action)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        _currentTask = _currentTask.ContinueWith(
            lastTask => 
            {
                // re-throw the error of the last completed task (if any)
                lastTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                // run the new task
                action();
            },
            CancellationToken.None, 
            TaskContinuationOptions.LazyCancellation, 
            TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var sleep = 1000 - i*100;
        QueueTask(() => 
        { 
            Thread.Sleep(sleep); 
            Debug.WriteLine("Slept for {0} ms", sleep); 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to do exactly what I wanted it to do. It took me a while to find the time to test this, but it's working great.

Comment: I've run into a potential problem with your code, but don't understand the code well enough yet to make a definitive call. It appears that the more actions I queue up, the longer each action takes. I'd say on average, each action takes 50ms (prior to implementing your suggested solution). That time is consistent at the start of my program, but once I've added about 100 actions, each action is taking 2 to 3 seconds. This happens even if all the queued actions have completed. Do you see anything off the top of your head that could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: @sdrev, the actions run strictly in serial manner here, one starts after another has finished. Perhaps, you wanted to start them in parallel, but complete in the order?

Comment: I understand that they run in serial, and that's the behavior I want and expect. The issue is that each discrete action is taking longer and longer. A single action takes about 50ms, so if I run 3 of them, I expect the last one to finish 150ms after I start queueing the actions. And that's what initially happens. However, the more actions I run through the queue, the longer each individual action is taking to execute. Assume I ran 100 actions through the queue, and I've let them all execute. The next action I add to the queue will take 2 seconds to execute, just by itself.

Comment: @sdrev, that's interesting. Try calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100)` before you start the while processing, does it improve the timing? If it does, I might have an explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not improve the timing. If it makes a difference, these actions only have to be serial on a "page" object that I've created. Pages are isolated from each other, so they all have their own QueueTask method. If the actions are slowing down on one Page and I switch to another Page, it functions quickly (initially; eventually it will slow down too).

Comment: @sdrev, I couldn't repro the slow-down with the exact code I posted. Can you? What exactly are you doing inside each action?

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Noseratio. I've finally tracked down the issue and it doesn't have anything to do with your code. I'm using a custom Clone() method inside the action that appears to have a bug that's causing it to take longer and longer to Clone the more times you call it.

Answer (score 2):

I think a proper solution would be to use a Queue, as it is FIFO in a task that is running in the background.

Your code could look something like this:

**Edit**

Edited to use Queue.Synchronize as @rwong mentioned (thanks!)

```
var queue = new Queue<MyCustomObject>();
//add object to the queue..
var mySyncedQueue = Queue.Synchronize(queue)

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var myObj = mySyncedQueue.Dequeue();
        if (myObj != null)
        { do work...}
    } 
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

This is just to get you started, im sure your could could be more efficient when you know exactly what is needed :)

**Edit 2**

As you are accessing the queue from multiple threads, it is better to use a ConcurrentQueue.
the method wont look much different:

```
var concurrentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<MyCustomObject>();
//add object to the queue..

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        MyCustomObject myObj;
        if (concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(myObj))
        { do work...}
    } 
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Comment: Why would you poll a concurrent queue with a CPU loop, so wasting a core, when blocking queues are available in BlockingCollection?

Comment: Wasnt familiar with BlockingQueue. You can post an answer so we can all learn

Answer (score 1):

Create exactly one background task. Then let it process all items in a thread-safe fifo buffer. Add objects to the fifo from your gui thread.

Comment: @rwong - which is why Mattias suggested 'Create exactly one background task' - sounds OK to me.